# Not Null in one side of Sqlalchemy Many to Many Relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables: Class_ and Student. I want to build a many to many relationship between them:

```
class Class_(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'classes'
    id = Column(Unicode(255), primary_key=True)

class Student(User):
    __tablename__ = "student"
    id = Column(Unicode(255), primary_key=True)
    classes = relationship('Class_', secondary='student_class_map',
                       backref='students', nullable=False)

class StudentClassMapping(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'student_class_map'

    student_id = Column(Unicode(255),
                        ForeignKey('student.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
                        primary_key=True)
    class_id = Column(Unicode(255),
                      ForeignKey('classes.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
                      primary_key=True)
```

I want to make sure that each Student object has at least one Class_ object related. So I add an `nullable=False` when declaring the relationship in Student class. However, it raised an error when running because relationship has no parameter named nullable.

Anyone can tell me the right way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question ? and also can you post the whole program on which you are working ?

Comment: Thanks Arpit. I have rephrased my question. Basically I want to find a way to achieve the same functionality as the nullable=false in one-many relationship. Hope you would understand.